# SurveyMonkey API not filtering on status

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I'm new to the SurveyMonkey API (and relatively new to Python in general).
I'm trying to retrieve the contacts that have either bounced or opted out (with 2 separate calls). This code was working last week (at that time, the query parameters were permissible on the `contacts/bulk endpoint` and they are now only on the `contacts` endpoint).

The code below is only returning active contacts (the default). It does 'accept' when I change the `per_page` parameter but I'm not sure why the `status` isn't working.
Where am I going wrong?

```
token = <our_token>
client = requests.session()
headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token,
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}

HOST = "https://api.surveymonkey.com"
EMAIL_ENDPOINT = "/v3/contacts"
OPTOUT = '?status=optout'
PER_PAGE = '&per_page=1000'
optout_url = "%s%s%s%s" % (HOST, EMAIL_ENDPOINT, OPTOUT, PER_PAGE)

optout_api = client.get(optout_url, headers=headers).json()
```

Answer (score 2):

nm. Heard back from SurveyMonkey and it's an issue on their end.

Comment: Hello wilmy, did they give you an estimated fix date?

Comment: I just got an email from them that this has been fixed 2 hours ago.